# JAVA Null pointer Exception getTitle method, I can't find it

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

There's no error while coding it, but when i ran it, it said

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at homework.Book.getTitle(Book.java:36)
    at homework.BookMain.main(BookMain.java:61)
Java Result: 1
```

```
***********************************
package homework;


public class BookMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i;
        int option;
        Book[] bookSet = new Book[20];
        bookSet[0] = new Book("I dare you","Joyce Meyer",2007);
        bookSet[1] = new Book("Straight from the Heart","Rev. Fr. Mario Jose C. Ladra",2012);
        bookSet[2] = new Book("Deliverance From Fear","Bob Buess",1993);
        bookSet[3] = new Book("Extraordinary Book of Facts","Bathroom Readers' Institute",2006);
        bookSet[4] = new Book("Fat Kid Rules the World","K.L. Going",2003);
        Book.numberOfBooks = 5;

        Book getter = new Book();

        for (i=0; i<Book.numberOfBooks; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(getter.getTitle(bookSet[i])+" "+getter.getAuthor(bookSet[i])+" "+getter.getYear(bookSet[i]));
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (i=0; i<Book.numberOfBooks; i++)
        {
            if(getter.getYear(bookSet[i])>2000)
                System.out.println(getter.getTitle(bookSet[i])+" "+getter.getAuthor(bookSet[i])+" "+getter.getYear(bookSet[i]));
        }

        bookSet[5] = new Book("The Lake of Dead Languages","Carol Goodman",2002);

        Shelf shelf1 = new Shelf("Shelf1","Bedroom");
        Shelf shelf2 = new Shelf("Shelf2","Living room");
        Shelf shelf3 = new Shelf("Shelf3","Basement");

        Shelf placer = new Shelf();
        placer.insertBook(shelf1,bookSet[1]);
        placer.insertBook(shelf1,bookSet[2]);

        placer.insertBook(shelf2,bookSet[3]);
        placer.insertBook(shelf2,bookSet[4]);

        placer.insertBook(shelf1,bookSet[5]);
        placer.insertBook(shelf1,bookSet[0]);

        System.out.println(placer.getShelfName(shelf1)+"     "+placer.getLocation(shelf1));
        Book aBookInShelf = new Book();

        for(i=0; i<shelf1.booksInShelf; i++)
        {
            aBookInShelf = placer.pickBook(shelf1, i);
            System.out.println(getter.getTitle(aBookInShelf)+"   "+getter.getAuthor(aBookInShelf)
                    +"   "+getter.getYear(aBookInShelf));
        }

    }
}

===========================================
Books class:
package homework;


public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int year;
    public static int numberOfBooks = 0;

    public Book(String title, String author, int year){
        this.title=title;
        this.author=author;
        this.year=year;
    }

    public Book(){

    }

    public String getAuthor(Book target){
        return target.author;
    }
    public int getYear(Book target){
        return target.year;
    }
    public String getTitle(Book target){
        return target.title;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
}

=====================================
Shelves class:

package homework;

public class Shelf {
    private String name;
    private String location;
    public static int booksInShelf=0;
    private Book[] shelfBooks = new Book[20];

    public Shelf(String name, String location){
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Shelf(){

    }

    public String getShelfName(Shelf target){
        return target.name;
    }

    public String getLocation(Shelf target){
        return target.location;
    }
    public void insertBook(Shelf target, Book aBook){
        target.shelfBooks[target.booksInShelf] = aBook;
        target.booksInShelf++;
    }
    public Book pickBook(Shelf target, int nthBook){
        return target.shelfBooks[nthBook];
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing stuff backwards. Why pass a target? Why not get the actual object's fields?

Comment: we we're not allowed to use public, so i made methods to return the attributes

Comment: You're thinking backwards. Instead of `public String getAuthor(Book target)` make it `public String getAuthor()`. Instead of `getter.getAuthor(someBook)`, do `someBook.getAuthor()` and return `this` object's field value.

Comment: Why is `int booksInShelf=0;` static?

Comment: There is so much wrong with your design. Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Comment: i made booksInShelf non-static and that solved everything, and i don't know why, I'm so sorry, its because we're just in the early days of my java introduction class. and im taking things slow in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

Beside getter/setter design madness it seems that NullPointerException is caused by fact that `booksInShelf` is static, which means that it belongs to entire `Shelf` class (instances of this class share value of this field) so when you add book to one `Shelf` and increment this field, it will be incremented for all instances of `Shelf`.

Because of that in loop

```
for(i=0; i<shelf1.booksInShelf; i++)
```

you are iterating even over positions that were not set yet and are still `nulls`. Now in

```
        aBookInShelf = placer.pickBook(shelf1, i);
        System.out.println(getter.getTitle(aBookInShelf)+"   "+getter.getAuthor(aBookInShelf)
                +"   "+getter.getYear(aBookInShelf));
```

you are picking this `null` and using it inside `getter.getTitle(null)` which will try to invoke `return null.title` which will case NPE because `null` doesn't have `title`.

---

To fix this problem remove `static` modifier from `booksInShelf` field.